How to fix this error No module named 'llama_index.llms.llama_cpp'
I am trying to use mixtral-8x7b with my own data with no luck. Here is my code
import torch
from llama_index.llms.llama_cpp import LlamaCPP
from llama_index.llms.llama_cpp.llama_utils import messages_to_prompt, completion_to_prompt
llm = LlamaCPP(
    model_url=None, # We'll load locally.
    model_path='./Models/mixtral-8x7b-instruct-v0.1.Q4_K_M.gguf', # 4-bit model
    temperature=0.1,
    max_new_tokens=1024, # Increasing to support longer responses
    context_window=8192, # Mistral7B has an 8K context-window
    generate_kwargs={},
    # set to at least 1 to use GPU
    model_kwargs={"n_gpu_layers": 40}, # 40 was a good amount of layers for the RTX 3090, you may need to decrease yours if you have less VRAM than 24GB
    messages_to_prompt=messages_to_prompt,
    completion_to_prompt=completion_to_prompt,
    verbose=True
)

Which gives error No module named 'llama_index.llms.llama_cpp'.
I have installed llama_index, used my MAC Mini and also Google Colab's GPUs
Any suggestions?

I think you also need to install llama-index-llms-llama-cpp and llama-index-embeddings-huggingface in addition to llama-index as suggested from the installation guide using the command below
pip install llama-index-llms-llama-cpp llama-index-embeddings-huggingface

